# How to set QTableView's horizontal header to default order?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtableview

I made horizontal header movable with
 `ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionsMovable(true);`
 How do I set to its original order?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if this is the right way. But the following code worked for me.

```
void MyWidget::resetColumnOrder()
{
    bool t= false;
    while(!t)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<m->columnCount();i++)
        {
        ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->moveSection(i, ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->visualIndex(i));
        }
        t=true;
        for(int i=0; i<m->columnCount();i++)
        {
            if(i!=ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->visualIndex(i))t=false;
        }
    }
}
```